# how to insert different table data into single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

table 1

```
Groupname   View
member      table a
non member  table b
teacher     table c
```

table a

```
id  key
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

TABLE B

```
ID  KEY
1   M
2   L
3   H
4   G
5   F
```

TABLE C

```
ID  KEY
1   Y
2   W
```

**output is**

```
GROUPNAME   KEY
member      A
member      B
member      C
non member  M
non member  L
non member  H
non member  G
non member  F
teacher     Y
teacher     W
```

Comment: A table Having groupname and view name and final out put table is group key and values of the views.please follow above Question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with a single query, then you might as well hardcode the names and use `union all`:

```
select 'member' as groupname, key
from a
union all
select 'non member' as groupname, key
from a
union all
select 'teacher' as groupname, key
from a;
```

I mean, you *could* replace the subqueries with:

```
select t1.groupname, key
from a join
     table1 t1
     on t1.view = 'a';
```

However, hardcoding the view name versus the `groupname` seems arbitrary.

If you wanted to do this more dynamically, you would need to use dynamic SQL.  Instead, I would advise you to change your data structure, combining the three tables and adding a `groupname` column.  Storing table and column names in tables is generally not a good approach to database design.

Comment: For dynamic how to write.

Comment: Dynamically how to write, If any groupname can added in feature, need to add manually.

Comment: @chaituchaitanyareddy You are not new and SO is not a free code-writing service. You encourage others to help by including a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A little searching will find examples of dynamic sql - which is the technique you will need to use to accomplish your goal. Alternatively you can ask the other sql developers in your organization for help - surely someone at your firm has this level of skill.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted by Gordon Linoff: I think your database design could use some work. If you were to write dynamic SQL in order to create the same type of query structure as Gordon had created in his answer, this would do the trick (provided each view had a "key" variable, and the tables were made using the default schema).

```
declare @t1 table ([groupname] varchar(20), [view] varchar(20))
insert into @t1 values ('member','table a'),('non member','table 3'),('teacher','table 4')
declare @q varchar(max)='', @groupname varchar(20),@viewname varchar(20)
declare c cursor for select [groupname],[view] from @t1 
    open c 
        fetch next from c into @groupname, @viewname
        while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 
        begin
            set @q=@q+'select '''+@groupname+''' as Groupname, '+QUOTENAME(@viewname)+'.[key] from '+QUOTENAME(@viewname)+'{$crlf}union all{$crlf}'
            fetch next from c into @groupname, @viewname
        end
    close c
deallocate c
set @q=replace(left(@q,len(@q)-23),'{$crlf}',CHAR(10))
print @q
exec (@q)
```